# How to change Single Element(integer) from 2D Arrays columns

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

**So i need to change Element (a integer) from column which is closest to that column average number.**
For example:

We have this 2D array     array[3][3]

1 4 7

2 5 8

3 6 9

So from first column i would need to change/replace 2 ((1+2+3)/3=2)
Because it is closest to average of column

For second column i would need to change/replace 5 ((4+5+6)/3=5)

For third 8

so in final version i would get

1 4 7

3 6 9

---

I "remove" element just by shortening the lenght of array and pushing numbers per 1 slot, here is how i do it for one-dimensional array

```
 int search(char A[], int B[], int n, char tp, int dd) //Search for number
{
    int ind = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if ((A[i] == tp) && (B[i] == dd))
            ind = i;
    return ind;
}
void remove(char A[], int B[], int & n, int ind) //remove number from array
{
    for (int i = ind; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        A[i] = A[i + 1];
        B[i] = B[i + 1];
    }
    n--;
```

I know how to remove elements in simple 1d array, but cant really come up with way of implementing to remove elements from 2d array

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please show your attempt at solving this task - even if it was unsuccessful. What exactly do you mean by "*remove element from an array*"? Do you know about `std::vector`?

Comment: _"We have this 2D array"_ That's a bunch of numbers, not a 2d array. Note that you can't remove any elements from raw c-style arrays. To do that you'll need a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` representation of the 2D array in your code.

Comment: I see, you have text, that represents (after interpretation) a 2d array. Are you storing the data in some `int array[3][3]` or some `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` container?

Comment: @KamilCuk i am storing data in array[3][3] just a simple integer array

Comment: There is no such thing as "removing" an item from an array.  An array's size if fixed.  What exactly do you mean by "removing"?

Comment: @Dj_Bear That array is fixed in size, you can't remove any elements there as mentioned. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: So you have `int array[3][3] = { {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {3, 6, 9}};` or `int array[3][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};`? Please edit your question and post relevant code and what have you tried?

Comment: @Dj_Bear *I know how to remove elements in simple 1d array* -- How can you do the impossible?  You cannot remove elements from an array.  You can *change* elements, but you cannot simply remove elements.

Comment: @Fureeish I dont any attempts at doing it for Two-dimensional array in particular, but i have it for one-dimensional array (https://pastebin.com/s7BE8Jz9)

Comment: @Dj_Bear -- In your code you posted (please post it here, not on pastebin), you are *changing* elements, you are not removing elements from the array.  Please note the difference between *changing* and *removing*.  The array is still `n` items in size.

Comment: I am so sorry for confusing everyone for saying that "i am removing element from array", but yeah i want to change value of element in each collumn

Comment: So what value do you use for the "changed" item?  Go back to your 1-d example.  You want to "remove" something, then the item that is no longer there has to be some value -- so what is this value?  `-1`?  `0`?  Or if not that, a shorter array means you have to keep track of the length, but you don't do that anywhere that I see.  Note that none of these questions would be asked *if* you used a type that actually removes items, such as `std::vector`.

Comment: Well i dont use any value in particular (but 0 to answer your question), because when i change value, i trim the lenght of array (1-d example array[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 }, need to "remove" 2, so then that array would be array[4] = { 1,3,4,5 }

Comment: So where do you remember the real length of the data?  The array is still 5 entries, so somewhere you need to keep track of the length.  I think you painted yourself into a corner by believing you were removing elements when you were not.  You would have needed to take care of all of these issues mentioned when using dumb arrays.

Comment: The number of elements stay constant  in each column, not necessarly in each row. A solution is to use a vector of vectors, and to use it to represent the transpose of the matrix. In a matrix,  for `M[i][j]` it is a pure convention that `i` represents a row and `j` a column. So you will only have to remove an element  in each vector `M[i]` representing a column

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i store array lenght in 'n' (from example) and thats why i minus 1 from n in for loop
  for (int i = ind; i < n - 1; i++)

Comment: @Damien something like this?
`void removeCol(int A[][CMax], int & n, int & m, int ind)
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
        for (int j = ind; j < m - 1; j++)
 { 

            A[i][j] = A[i][j + 1];
        }
    }
 
    m--;
}`

Comment: Yes but ind depends on `i` of course, and if some obscure forces request you to use C-style arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is to remove one element in each column.

Therefore, the number of elements remains constant in each column, not necessarly in each row.

A solution is to use a vector of vectors, and to use it to represent the *transpose* of the matrix. In a matrix `M`, for each `M[i][j]` element, it is a pure convention that `i` represents a row and `j` a column. Taking the inverse is equivalent to reverse this convention.

So you will only have to remove one element in each vector `M[i]` representing a column.

It is easy to adapt this method for classical C-style arrays, if one is forced to.

PS: the mentioned convention is not universal. For channel coding for example, the specialists use line-vectors. Then the matrices used are the transpose of what they should be with a classical raw-vector convention.